# Looking for old episode where Dr. Who is in a computer simulation on Gallifrey

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

Can somebody tell me about a Dr. Who episode where he was stuck inside a computer simulation? I think the episode was on his home planet of Gallifrey. I think it starred Tom Baker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In "[The Deadly Assassin](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Deadly_Assassin_(TV_story))" (which did indeed star Tom Baker and was set on Gallifrey), the Doctor enters the virtual reality world of the Matrix where he comes up against

> the Master.

Answer (score 7):

In "[The Ultimate Foe](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ultimate_Foe_(TV_story))", the end of "The Trial of a Time Lord" (which actually stars *Colin* Baker and was set on Gallifrey), the Doctor enters the virtual reality world of the Matrix where he comes up against

> the Master.

Comment: Strange that the last sentence here is exactly the same as in the previous answer - and that refers to a different episode.

Comment: @Wikis they both accurately describe what happens :)

Comment: I suppose that your spoiler is correct - however, mine was the actual ultimate foe (in "The Ultimate Foe", no less), and I think he showed up in the Matrix as well. My apologies if I misrecalled.

Comment: @RDFozz the Valyard isn't a spoiler - he's known all season.

Comment: He's *present* all season - our view of his role does change somewhat at the end.

Comment: @RDFozz also the main point of this answer is to be the same as Moriarty's :p